# Definition of $p$-torsion module

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, modules, definition

Let $p$ be a prime. What is the definition of a $p$-torsion module ? I have googled but was not convinced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\;M\;$ be a module over a ring $\;R\;$, then

$$M_p:=\left\{ x\in M\;;\;x^{p^n}=1\;,\;\;p\;\text{a fixed prime}\;,\;n\in\Bbb N\;\right\}$$

is called the $\;p-$ torsion submodule of $\;M\;$ .

Comment: Didn't you mean $p^nx=0$ (the same as for abelian groups)? I mean, in a module there need not be a product $M\times M\to M$, that would be an $R$-algebra, so $x^k$ is not well-defined.

Comment: @Javi Yes...but then in fact $\;p^nx=0\;$...